# Kafka Streams API: Using multiple filters and a default topic

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I'm using the KStream `filter` functionality to write to a specific topic based on a matching predicate:

```
val builder: KStreamBuilder = new KStreamBuilder()
val stream: KStream[String, String] = builder.stream(config)

val filter1 = stream.filter(predicate1)
val filter2 = stream.filter(predicate2)

filter1.to("out-topic-1")
filter2.to("out-topic-2")

new KafkaStream(builder, properties).start
```

How can I make sure that if a message does not match any of these filters it would still be written to a default topic? I've tried defining an output for the "default" stream without any luck:

```
stream.to("default-topic")
```

Thanks for any help on the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `KStream#branch` -- it takes multiple predicates and the last predicate could just return `true` unconditionally. If you use `branch` a record will be contained in exactly one output stream. Your logic from above is a little bit different atm, as a record could end up in both output streams (filter1 and filter2). If you need to preserve this `branch` won't work, but you could add the following to make the second case work:

```
val default = stream.filterNot(predicate1).filterNot(predicate2)
default.to("default-topic");
```